# How to fix Validation error of type SubSelectionNotAllowed

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm getting the following error when calling a lambda function through AppSync GraphQL:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": null,
      "locations": [{ "line": 2, "column": 3, "sourceName": null }],
      "message": "Validation error of type SubSelectionNotAllowed: Sub selection not allowed on leaf type String of field sendSignatureRequest @ 'sendSignatureRequest'"
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't seen this error before. Where should I be looking to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The lambda function returns a string and I coded an object in the query.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: the return type of the function has to match the return expected by appsync.